# Httpclient authorization with multiple token

Tags: c#, multithreading, dotnet-httpclient

I have different secretKeys to authenticate one url. I dont want to create multiple httpClient for each authorization. is there a way that I can send multiple secret keys in one object of httpClient? Or I can authenticate url with all secret keys parallel in multiplethreading?

```
string baseAdd = "some url";
    string[] secretKeys = new string[] { "key1", "key2", "key3"};
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAdd) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", secretKey[0]);
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "login")
                });
    response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Does your `some url` accept multiple keys? This sounds a bit weird as i would expect there is a token and url pairing. So you just need to write a function that takes url and token and sets them?

Comment: Yes this is the url for directline in bot framework which can be authenticated by multiple secret key.

Comment: So then why do you need multiple? just leave one? why does it matter which one to use and how does the app know which one to use?

Comment: Based on secret key, it decides which channel it needs to authenticate. here is the detail - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication)

Comment: Why not use an HttpRequestMessage and set the authorization headers there?

Comment: @Vikram what that says is that 'direct line secret' is retrieved ONCE; and tken is refreshed. You totally don't need to have that code lumped together. As i said before, you need to pass 2 parameters to this method - URL and Token.\

Comment: @john , how would I add multiple authentcation header using HttpRequestMessage? Can you please explain?

Comment: Do you mean multiple authentication headers in one request? Your question said that you didn't want to create multiple `HttpClient` objects. Methods like [PostAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L322-L328) are just wrappers around creating an `HttpRequestMessage` and then calling `SendAsync(message)`. You can do away with your _DefaultRequestHeaders_ (default!) and instead set the headers on the message object (`message.Headers.Authorization = ....`). If this works for you, I'll add an answer later.

Comment: @john why answer the question in a comment? Sounds like the correct answer to me, I'd upvote it :)

Comment: @ToddMenier I wasn't entirely sure what he wanted and I didn't have time :)

Answer (score 2):

`DefaultRequestHeaders` are just that: the default headers for any requests sent through the `HttpClient`. As implied by "Default", they can be set elsewhere. Methods like [PostAsync(...)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L322-L328) are simply wrappers around creating a request object and sending it via `SendAsync(message)`.

So you can simply define HttpClient somewhere, statically:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

And then create the message and apply your headers to that.

```
HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://www.site.tld/blah");
message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Moo");
message.Content = new StringContent("{\"a\": 5}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
```